# .htaccess добавить слеш в конце URI и убрать .html

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, redirect, apache2, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://site.tk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
```

Собственно, таким образом я убрал .html .
А вот как ко всем URI используя текущий код добавить в конце / (слеш), чтобы не получился бесконечный редирект?

То есть 
со страниц site.ru/page.html в site.ru/page
и 
со страниц любой вложенности site.ru/catalog/page.html в site.ru/catalog/page

Comment: дополните свой вопрос примером url-а, который необходимо преобразовать, а также напишите url, который надо получить на выходе.

Comment: @defrag 
со страниц site.ru/page.html в site.ru/page и со страниц любой вложенности site.ru/catalog/page.html в site.ru/catalog/page